# Getting error while getting credentials from aws secret manager and connecting to dynamoDB in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-secrets-manager

I am getting below error when trying to connect to dynamoDB after getting credentials from aws secret manager.

```
Uncaught (in promise) CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

But when I try with hardcoded keys, it's working fine. Can anyone conform what I am doing wrong here. Below is my code:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const region = 'my-region';
const SecretId = "secret-name";
const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});
client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: SecretId }).promise()
.then((secretValue: any)=>{
    const secretString = JSON.parse(secretValue.SecretString)
    console.log(secretString)
    AWS.config.update({
        region: region,
        accessKeyId: secretString.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: secretString.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    });
});
```

Based on request by @leehannigan

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

const dynamoConnect = async () => {
    const secretName = "my-keys";
    let secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region: 'region'
    });
    try {
        let secretValue = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}).promise();
        const creds = JSON.parse(secretValue.SecretString);
        AWS.config.update({
            region: 'region',
            accessKeyId: creds.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: creds.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          });
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
} 

const fetchData = async (tableName : any, studentId : any) => {
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    await dynamoConnect()
    let params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        FilterExpression: `studentId = :studentId`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':studentId': studentId
          }
    }
    return data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    
}
```

Comment: Where does AWS get the credentials to interact with Secrets Manager? Storing AWS access keys in Secrets Manager seems pointless, since you also need AWS access keys to interact with Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You must `await` the getting keys, as its an async function call.

#### includes edit

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

const dynamoConnect = async () => {
    const secretName = "my-keys";
    let secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region: 'region'
    });
    try {
        let secretValue = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}).promise();
        const creds = JSON.parse(secretValue.SecretString);
        AWS.config.update({
            region: 'region',
            accessKeyId: creds.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: creds.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          });
      console.log("set config")
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
} 

const fetchData = async (tableName : any, studentId : any) => {
    await dynamoConnect()
    console.log("creating client")
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    
    let params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        FilterExpression: `studentId = :studentId`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':studentId': studentId
          }
    }
    return data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    
}
```

Instead, you should await the response from secrets manager:

```
const creds = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: SecretId }).promise();

AWS.config.update({
  region: region,
  accessKeyId: creds.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: creds.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

// Now everything after here will wait to the AWS Config is updated
```

##### `await` vs `.then()`

```
const p1 = new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res("p1"), 1000));

p1.then(res=>console.log(res));
console.log("hello");


const fun = async()=>{
    const result = await p1;
    console.log("Waited")
}

fun();
```

Comment: Tried that also, but still getting same error.

Comment: Please share the entire code.

Comment: shared code in above comment

Comment: Using `.then()` on a promise is the same thing as using `await`. `await` is just a new language construct that does the `.then()` part for you. There's no functional difference in the two versions of code in this answer.

Comment: That is not true, `.then()` is more likened to a callback, not an await. Any code following will be executed. I've added a simple piece of code to show that.

Comment: @RanjanKumar I asked you to share code, but the key part is missing, where you create the `docClient`. From where did you obtain this?

Comment: @LeeHannigan I have updated the code, docClient in inside fetchData function

Comment: Your issue is that you create the DynamoDB client before configuring the AWS Config. Use the code I posted in `edit`.

Comment: Tried that too, still same issue

Comment: I added to log lines, share the order those logs are printed with me.

Comment: able to log before secretsManager.getSecretValue, after that getting error. But if I add hardcoded config before that, it works fine and able to log after this line also.

Comment: Check the values you get from secrets manager are actual credentials.